# Creating folder not working

Tags: android, directory, android-permissions

i am trying to create a folder for my app and this is my code :

```
File folder= new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "myFolder" );
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            // Do something on success
        } else {
            // Do something else on failure
        }
```

Plus, i have inserted in the manifest.xml file the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

even though , it still not working.

Any help ? Regards.

Comment: Any error and was success true or not

Comment: no erros, and the success was false.

Comment: what is ur targetsdk and the device vrsion ur testing?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

Comment: check my answer and i was asking target sdk and running device os verion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for marshmallow and above devices you have to handle permissions runtime for storage, location, mocrophone etc. so when target sdk is greater than equal 23 and then device having marshmallow or above set permission off by default which you have to handle run time go through this link for info https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Now if i handle permissions runtime for the target sdk inferior to 25 (even though they don't need as u described above) will i encounter any issues ? Regards.

Comment: if you targeting 23 or above better you use run time permission model that first u check permission is granted then proceed to task related permission it will not affect lower version.
 if it worked  for u then you can accept this as answer tahnks

Comment: @JoeDa its mine mistake marshmallow sdk is 23 so it applies from 23 and above edited same in answer too

Comment: i am trying to accept it as an answer, but apparently my reputation won't allow me. Sorry.

Comment: I think It will not require minimum reputation you just click on accept icon for vote you need minimum reputation anyway accepting answer is to know other users that question is resolved glad it helped u ☺